# Use promise with async

Tags: angular, angular6

I'd like to get `Object` using `Promise`.
Bellow, is the method:

```
async getUri()
  {
      var data = this.userService.getOrders();
      var outside_uri = await data.then((uri) => { console.log('inside => ' + uri); return uri;})
      console.log('outside => ' + outside_uri)
  }
```

where

```
getOrders(): Promise<Profession[]>
    {
        return this.http.get<Profession[]>(`${this.baseUrl}/users/professions/id/2`)
                        .toPromise()
                        .then((response) => response);
    }
```

But when I call this method on **ngOnInit()** like that:

```
console.log("-----Result: " + this.getUri());
```

It produces:

> -----Result: [object Promise]
>
> inside => [object Object]
>
> outside => [object Object]

Have you please any idea about solving that ?. Big Thanks.

Comment: `this.getUri().then(uri => console.log('-----Result:' + uri))` or you need `await this.getUri()`

Comment: Hello Sir @AlexanderStaroselsky, thanks for your reply I tried `console.log(this.getUri().then(uri => console.log('-----Result:' + uri)));`, but, I got  `inside => [object Object]
outside => [object Object]
-----Result:undefined`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code has a tiny mistake in `getOrders` function since you're solving the promise within the body of the method , and the function expect you to get a promise

So edit your code to fit the following

```
getOrders(): Promise<any>
    {
        return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/users/professions/id/2`)
                        .toPromise();
    }
```

And

```
async getUri()
  {
      let data = this.userService.getOrders();
      let outside_uri;
      await data.then((uri) => { 
           console.log('inside => ' + uri); 
           outside_uri = uri;
        })
      console.log('outside => ' + outside_uri)
  }
```

Comment: Hello Sir @Abdurahman, thanks for your reply, but I got `-----Result: [object Promise] 
inside => [object Object]
outside => [object Object]` when I call **this.getUri()** on **ngOnInit()**

Comment: Then try not to cast it to ``Profession[]`` until you sure that your ``API`` gives you a result you can cast it to

Comment: See updated answer and tell me what it prints

Comment: Hello Sir @Abdulrahman, I tried your proposition. I got                                               `--------------[object Promise]
inside => [object Object]
outside => [object Object]`

Comment: this url got `{
    "id": 2,
    "libelle": "Engineer",
    "selected": false
}`

Comment: Ok Sir, it solved. On init, I made `this.getUri().then(num => console.log(num));`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `await` to wait for the promise to resolve.

You need to `await` `this.userService.getOrders();` and `this.getUri()` in your `console.log`

So your `console.log` should look like:

```
var uri = await this.getUri()
console.log("-----Result: " + uri);
```

Comment: Hello Sir @Viqas, thanks for your reply. I tried  `async getUri() {var data = await this.userService.getOrders();}` and called `console.log("--------------" + this.getUri());` on **ngOnInit()** , I got `--------------[object Promise]`

Comment: I meant you also need to await in your console.log, take a look at my updated answer.

Comment: Thank Sir, getUri is async so I got `await is only allowed within an async function`

Comment: move the call to `this.getUri()` out then, then log the value after. See my updated answer.

Comment: I got the same error Sir.

Comment: You need to make sure the function you are using `await` in, is an `async` function.

Comment: Ok Sir, but as i made in my question **async** getUri()